# adding custom filter in yii2 grid

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have created a yii2 grid with crud. In the date column I want a filter which has two inputs, one is from date and another is to date, and it filters the data between those two dates.

Answer (score 0):

All has been done.
For your knowledge I am putting this answer.

```
   <form action="http://localhost/singla_cons/backend/web/attendenceview" method ="get">
From:<input type="date" class="fdate" name="AttendenceviewSearch[from_date]" >
To:<input type="date" class="fdate"  name="AttendenceviewSearch[to_date]">
<input type="submit" val ue="Get">
</form>
```

Use this in your view function.

after that in your model function

```
public $from_date;
```

public $to_date;

```
->andFilterWhere(['>=','date',$this->from_date])
    ->andFilterWhere(['<=','date',$this->to_date]);
```

and all is done.